# How do I count and group by time column per the last three months in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, time

Hello I'm having trouble with my code.  With mysql i'm trying to get a count of 'id' column in a purchases table based for the last 3 months..

So i want to count how many purchases made in the last 3 months using mysql. I have a time column which uses timestamp if that helps.

My code below doesn't work..

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id)  
          FROM purchases
          where username='$username' 
          GROUP BY time";
```

Comment: Why would you use group for this? It should be WHERE time > TIMESTAMPADD(MOTNH, -3, NOW()). You could use GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m', time) to get a list of the previous months with their number of puchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id)  
          FROM purchases
          WHERE username='$username' 
          AND timecol BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND NOW()";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering why your query fails, it's probably because `time` is a MySQL keyword and should be escaped, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id)  
          FROM purchases
          WHERE username = '$username' 
          GROUP BY `time`";
```

As for how to only select purchase records for the last three months, see the other answers.